# Salesforce - Create index for child records

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an account and I have multiple child records for this Account.

I would like to create a custom field and then update 1 for the first record created and if another record is created I want a field to populate 2 on the second and so on.

I want to develop this functionality because I want to track first record, second record for our analytics.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: If all you care about is the order they were created in, just order them by created date.

Comment: Thanks but my requirement is way ahead of Querying...